# Condensing repetitive code with google scripts

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Pretty new to all this but have a simple script to pull API info and put into google sheets. I want to pull the top 20 coins but I'm unsure of how to do it as a ??'function'?? to limit the amount of code required presently especially since only 'XXX' is basically changing. Thanks in advance

````
 var urlBTC='https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1d&limit=2';
 var responseBTC = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlBTC,{'muteHttpExceptions': true});
 var jsonBTC = responseBTC.getContentText();
 var parseBTC = JSON.parse(jsonBTC);

 sheetBTC.getRange(3,3).setValue(parseBTC[0][6]);


 var sheetETH = sh.getSheetByName("ETH");
 var urlETH='https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=ETHUSDT&interval=1d&limit=2';
 var responseETH = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlETH,{'muteHttpExceptions': true});
 var jsonETH = responseETH.getContentText();
 var parseETH = JSON.parse(jsonETH);

 sheetETH.getRange(3,3).setValue(parseETH[0][6]);

}```
````

Comment: I assume you know how to obtain a list of top 20 coins from the API you are using? If so, you can try looping through the list then use string concatenation to pass into the URL parameters. I will give you a more detailed answer if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var coins = ['ETHUSDT','BTCUSDT']
    function getCoin(){
     coins.forEach(coin => {
       let url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol='+ coin
      + '&interval=1d&limit=2'

      //do the other stuff
      })
     }
```

Hope this helps set you off in the right direction.

Basically we store the symbols as an array loop through and create a url for that, in the 'do something' put in your other code for handling the req. watch out for rate limits

Comment: Tried this method but keep getting forEach.coin is not a function. Appreciate the help though. Will keep searching

Comment: @Upland is the syntax being followed correctly? just ran a test with the code above and was able to generate the URLs. Just bringing this up because you typed forEach.coin

I corrected my mistake of forearch to forEach.

Comment: Thank you sir... I was going to start studying Array Loops tonight. Very much appreciated.

Comment: If you other questions let me know